# Change RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY of FetchContent library

Tags: c++, cmake

How do you change the runtime output of a cmake dependency pulled with `FetchContent`?

I've tried setting the usual `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_<CONFIG>` but the targets are ignoring this setting.

Here is an example of how I'm setting the runtime output. Very well could be a user error, but I've scoured the documentation and search, I haven't seen any hint on how to redirect runtime output.

```
FetchContent_Declare(Potato
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://git.superpotato.com
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(Potato)

set_target_properties(PotatoLib
    PROPERTIES
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${POTATO_BIN_DIR}
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG ${POTATO_BIN_DIR}
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE ${POTATO_BIN_DIR}
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELWITHDEBINFO ${POTATO_BIN_DIR}
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was elsewhere, this works.